# Query record + 6 rows before and after?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I want to be able to query a subset that includes the correct record and then the 6 before and after for 13 rows total and display them in a DGV.  The query to pull the correct row is as follows:

```
private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses3DataContext db = new DataClasses3DataContext();

        var matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                          where c.HOUSE_NO.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Direction.Contains(textBox2.Text) && c.street.Contains(textBox3.Text) && c.SUFF.Contains(textBox4.Text)
                          select c).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: do you have an auto incrementing ID column?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about the ID column.  No its not auto incrementing as it is stored by a unique value referred to has a PARCEL number which more or less corresponds with the property address.

Comment: so are they ordered correctly? you just want to find item X and just take the 6 rows before and 6 rows after that in the database ?

Comment: That is correct Thousand.

Answer (score 0):

if the PARCEL number is increasing then use your query to retrieve the parcel number.

Then:

```
var before = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                      where c.PARCEL < retrievedParcelNumber orderby c.PARCEL descending 
                      select c).Take(6);

var after = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                      where c.PARCEL > retrievedParcelNumber orderby c.PARCEL
                      select c).Take(6);
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<CityCollectionCSharp.prop>' does not contain a definition for 'take' and no extension method 'take' accepting a first argument of type'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<CityCollectionCSharp.prop>'

Comment: hmm Take should begin with an uppercase 'T'. Check if this is the problem

Comment: That fixed it thanks.  How would I push the results to a DataGridView?  Never done this when its 3 queries.